# Build on Galaxy S

Tags: codenameone

Until around 1-2 months ago the `android` build (of any app) was running perfectly on `Android Galaxy S`. Now the buid cannot be installed on this device. I added the flag `codename1.arg.android.min_sdk_version=7` and the application is installed but when running it a 'Force Close' message is prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try debugging your app using Android ddms in eclipse first, It will point you to where the error is coming from. With the StackTrace, you can get the help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We transitioned the `Google Play Services` support to be on by default as that is the common use case and makes API's like the location API far more usable.

As a result 2.3.1 became the minimum OS version as imposed by Google. If you want to reduce the minimum back to 2.2.x and don't need `Google Play Services` you can use `android.includeGPlayServices=false`.

Comment: Thanks Shai! Works perfect.

Comment: It seems that I cannot install on Galaxy S. after android.includeGPlayServices was deprecated

Comment: Try setting `android.gradle=false` Google effectively cut support for the older OS's as they are moving with gradle and discarding legacy. We need to keep up with them.

Comment: FYI  you need to accept correct answers with the checkbox next to the answer